# How to play Thud!?

Tags: discworld, games

There is a page devoted to the game of Thud! from Pratchett's Discworld, but it is not well maintained. They have the semi-official rules to play, but I am afraid they are incomplete and quite obscure.

Is there a better description of the rules, unambiguous and covering all situations?

Comment: See also: [Can I use my Tafl game to play Thud?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/6239/2133)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [board game of Thud!](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4532/thud) was released several years ago. The [rules are available online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Games_of_the_Discworld#Gameplay)

> On the dwarfs' turn, they may either move or hurl one dwarf:
>
> **Move**: any one dwarf is moved like a chess queen, any number of squares
>   in any orthogonal or diagonal direction, but not onto or through any
>   other piece, whether Thudstone, dwarf, or troll;
>
> or
>
> **Hurl**: anywhere
>   there is a straight (orthogonal or diagonal) line of adjacent dwarfs
>   on the board, they may hurl the front dwarf in the direction
>   continuing the line, as long as the space between the lead dwarf and
>   the troll is less than the number of dwarfs in the line. This is
>   different from a normal move in that the dwarf is permitted to land on
>   a square containing a troll, in which case the troll is removed from
>   the board and the dwarf takes his place. This may only be done if the
>   endmost dwarf can land on a troll by moving in the direction of the
>   line at most as many spaces as there are dwarfs in the line. Since a
>   single dwarf is a line of one in any direction, a dwarf may always
>   move one space to capture a troll on an immediately adjacent square.
>
> On the trolls' turn, they may either move or shove one troll:
>
> **Move**: one troll is moved like a chess king, one square in any
>   orthogonal or diagonal direction onto an empty square. After the troll
>   has been moved, only a single dwarf on the eight squares adjacent to
>   the moved troll may optionally be immediately captured and removed
>   from the board, at the troll player's discretion; 
>   or
>
> **Shove**: anywhere
>   there is a straight (orthogonal or diagonal) line of adjacent trolls
>   on the board, they may shove the endmost troll in the direction
>   continuing the line, up to as many spaces as there are trolls in the
>   line. As in a normal move, the troll may not land on an occupied
>   square, and any (all) dwarfs in the eight squares adjacent to its
>   final position may immediately be captured. Trolls may only make a
>   shove if by doing so they capture at least one dwarf.
>
> The battle is
>   over when both players agree that no more captures can be made by
>   continuing to play, or when one player has no more valid moves to
>   make. At this point the players count score: the dwarfs score 1 point
>   for each surviving dwarf, and the trolls score 4 for each remaining
>   troll, with the difference being the 'final' score. The players should
>   then swap sides to play another round, and the sum of their final
>   scores for the two battles determines the overall victor.